# Why is the ocean darker when it is windy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, visible-light, water

There are a lot of questions and answers on this site about ocean color, but none of them addresses my question.

I have found this too:

https://science.nasa.gov/earth-science/oceanography/living-ocean/ocean-color

But neither this does specifically address the darker ocean color when it is windy.

Even if there are no clouds, and there is clear sky, but windy, the color of the ocean is darker.

Colder parts of the ocean are sometimes darker, but being windy does not mean that the water itself cools down that fast. Even when the wind picks up the water color turns darker right away without cooling down.

The surface is more wavy, that is a given, when it is windy, but waves themselves could even make the water brighter, not darker.

Waves turn sometimes even white (when they break), because of bubbles, so this can't explain it either.

Question:

1. Why is the ocean darker when it is windy?

Comment: Do you have pictures with and without wind? Usually there are clouds when it is windy so you have less lighting.

Comment: In general, if the wind is blowing along the coast or out to sea, then it would push the warmer water on the surface away from the beach - which allows for the colder water beneath to upwell - the colder water being dark because it should be colder and should contain more nutrients then there are in the warmer water surface water. If the wind is blowing at the beach then you may have the downwelling of warm water.

Comment: I think reflection is also of relevance. For any given angle between observer and see surface only part of the latter will look as a mirror.